# Sorting/grouping collections for an archive

Tags: html, sorting, grouping, jekyll

I am building my first site and am having a very difficult time grouping/sorting collections. The only success I have had is a list of files sorted alphabetically by subdirectory, then by files by their dates (seems to be the default) using:

```
<ul>
  {% for page in site.collection_name | sort: weight %}
      <a href="{{ page.url }}"><h3>{{ page.title }}</h3></a>{{ page.category }}{{page.excerpt}}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Weight (above) does not work. Neither did type, category, or any other variable I substituted.

My files are in subdirectories, and have permalinks as:

/collection_name/category_name/file_name/

Front matter includes:
title,
category,
layout,
type,
(tried several others)

The collection will have several file types such as:
articles,
videos,
research

What I want to accomplish is something that loops through my collection first for category, then by type. In very bad pseudo code:

```
<ul>
{% for page in site.{{category_name}} %}
<li><h2>{{category01}}</h2></li>

    <ul>
    {% for type in site.{{category_name.type}} | sort: date reverse%}
    <li><h3>Articles</h3></li>
        <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>{{page.excerpt}}</li>

    <li><h3>Videos</h3></li>
        <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>{{page.excerpt}}</li>

    <li><h3>Research</h3></li>
      <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>{{page.excerpt}}</li>
    </uL>

<li><h2>{{category02}}</h2></li>
. . .

   . . . {% endfor %}
```

Any help or direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `group_by` :

```
{% assign byCategory = site.collection_name | group_by: 'category' | sort: 'name' %}
{% for cat in byCategory %}
  <h2>{{ cat.name | capitalize }}</h2>
  {% assign byType = cat.items | group_by: 'type' %}
  {% for type in byType %}
    <h3>{{ type.name | capitalize }}</h3>
    <ul>
      {% for item in type.items %}
        <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: this works with `category: mycategory` not with `categories: [one, two]`

If you want to specifically order types, you can do :

**_config.yml**

```
# this array determine types order
# a collection itm with non matching type will not be listed
types :
  - articles
  - videos
  - research
```

**code**

```
{% assign byCategory = site.area | group_by: 'category' %}
{% for cat in byCategory %}
  <h2>{{ cat.name }}</h2>
  {% assign byType = cat.items | group_by: 'type' %}
  {% for type in site.types %}
    {% assign currentType = byType | where:"name", type | first %}
    <h3>{{ currentType.name | capitalize }}</h3>
    <ul>
      {% for item in currentType.items %}
          <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, David. This seems to be working. (I am using dummy content). For others reading this, cupcakes and Cupcakes are different categories.

Comment: David, what is controlling the order of 'type'. The date/time created? Can these be changed to a specific order?

Comment: Order of type depends on alphabetical order of posts. For a specific ordering see answer edit.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you again. I was about to give up on Jekyll.